Active research areas in Cryptography
I am student having Math background. I want to shift in the direction of cryptography and willing to do my PhD in it.
I want to explore different areas of cryptography before choosing one.
What are the active areas of research in crypto?
Which areas of crypto will be used by industries in 5-6 years from now? I have heard that Blockchain is one such topic.

For the currently active areas you can take a look at the recent conferences of the International Association for Cryptologic Research (Crypto/EuroCrypt/AsiaCrypt are the main "general" conferences, the others focus on a subtopic). Thanks to Covid the last conferences were virtual, so you can see them on IACR's youtube channel. About industries: My personal opinion of Blockchain is a bit skeptical, it is/was quite hyped up. I'd see more future in post-quantum crypto, but look also at https://rwc.iacr.org/.

@j.p. What is the future of Searchable Encryption in industry based labs in the next 5-6 years?

Sorry, no idea.

For very mathy research have a look at Elliptic Curve cryptography (isogenies). More generally, Post-Quantum cryptography is very active. There's NIST competition on that, although it should finish somewhere soon.
In blockchain, I think there are two large directions of research: on advanced cryptographic primitives (e.g. ZK-proofs, various cool signatures) and on privacy/economic/game-theoretic aspects. There's currently quite a lot of funding for research and probably easy to find a job in some blockchain company.
Secure cryptographic implementations is also a very active and industry-oriented topic.

Adding links: NIST's PKC competition and FAQ on the threats of hypothetical Cryptographically Relevant Quantum Computers.

Could you tell me if Searchable Encryption is an industry oriented topic?

You could of course take a look at BlockChain within a Post-Quantum world, if you want to combine the two. There seems to be both a lack of research and lack of interest from the block chains themselves but we get - now and then - questions from users on the topic.

"There's NIST competition on that, although it should finish somewhere soon."; the NIST competition is focusing on the basics of public key crypto (KEM, Encryption, Signatures) - they have stated that they'll continue looking (Round 4 alternatives + an "on ramp" for novel non-lattice-based signature proposals).  And, there will also need for work on more advanced primitives (DAA, Threshold signatures, PAKE, IBE, ABE, Homomorphic...).  Things are far from over yet...
